# Apple's Using C++ with Objective-C article is gone... Can anyone give me a new article, or help me find the old one?

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

If one searches for mixing objective-c and c++ this link invariably comes up as THE solution.

[Using C++ With Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/chapter_14_section_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH10-SW1)

Unfortunately it's dead. Does anyone know where this article has moved, have an alternative article, or have some code demonstrating two way chatter between objective-c and c++ objects (calling both from the other). I can architect around an inability to call objective-c from c++, but I would much prefer to have the freedom to perform callbacks.

I have gotten as far as instantiating a c++ object and calling methods on it from objective-c++, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get the c++ to call back or how to properly declare the c++ object in the objective-c++ object's header file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The article is still available on the WayBack Machine (`web.archive.org`). The [latest snapshot](http://web.archive.org/web/20081231010709/http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/chapter_14_section_1.html) appears to be from december 31, 2008.

Comment: Brilliant, I tried to use way back machine but I guess I didn't go far enough into the past.