# Storing Objective-C class instance in C++ class

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

Is there a way to store an Objective-C class instance inside of a C++ class as a member?

Comment: Have you tried it in a .mm?

Comment: I have but I get some kind of memory error when I try to set it

Comment: In my own code, I've done this with the instance being a "`void *`", but if you want to *access* the Objective-C pieces, you'll need to write glue that lives in a .m or .mm file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a .mm file, and then you can use the features outlined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B).  See also [a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8105810/480850) to Apple's old documentation on the hybrid language.