# IS there a way to wrap a Objective-C Object with a C++ Class

Tags: c++, objective-c

IS there a way to wrap a Objective-C Object with a C++ Class?

I want to be able to control a Objective-C Class with C++

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "wrap".

Comment: Have a C++ class with a Obj-C Object inside it which the C++ can talk to

Comment: You can have a C++ class with an Objective-C *object pointer* inside it.  And with Objective-C++ (.mm file) you can invoke methods of the Objective-C object from the C++ code.  A minor song and dance may be required to "bridge" the pointer into the C++ object.

Comment: How many times do you feel you need to ask this question? If you're not getting the answers you want, please elaborate and be more specific. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106068/storing-objective-c-class-instance-in-c-class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106068/storing-objective-c-class-instance-in-c-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Objective-C++ option to enable the two languages to be used in the same translation. The file extension for an ObjC++ source is `.mm`. Xcode, GCC, and Clang have supported this for years.

```
class Wrapped { NSObject * object; };
```

You can also use a plain `id`, which is a C compatible type declared in the objc headers -- then you could use your wrapper in C++ (no ObjC required).

```
class Wrapped { id object; };
```

Comment: But you kinda need Objective-C++ to actually use the object.

Comment: @HotLicks hehe. It's only useful when you need to message it. Really, you *could* message using C or asm :p Of course, I'm not recommending that, but the more common case of preferring `id` would be to hide the messaging in the implementation so that you can avoid exposing the ObjC type to C++ sources -- compiling ObjC++ is resource intensive. In some cases, it helps to use `id` to reduce dependencies, compilation times, and to avoid compiling as ObjC++. More often, it is better to preserve type, and build with ObjC++.

Comment: Or, just write a wrapper, using Objective-C++.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use Objective-C++?