# How can I initialize an automatic member with a custom constructor in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, constructor, objective-c++

I have a C++ class with a custom constructor.

```
struct Inner {
    int i_;
    Inner(int i): i_(i) {}
};
```

I'd like to use it as an automatic member of an Objective-C class.

If I did the same thing in C++, I'd pass the argument to the member's constructor in the initialization list:

```
class Outer {
    Inner inner_;

    public:

    // Automatic member variables with custom constructors must
    // be initialized in the parent struct's initialization list.
    Outer(int i): inner_(i) {}

    // This will cause an error
    //Outer() {}

    int val() { return inner_.i_; }
};
```

In Objective-C, it would look something like this:

```
@interface Outer () {
    Inner inner_;
}
@end

@implementation Outer

- (instancetype)initWithValue:(NSInteger)i
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // ...
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)val {
    return inner_.val();
}
```

But I don't know where I can pass a value to Inner's constructor, since Objective-C doesn't have initializer lists. This generate a compiler error, `"No matching constructor for initialization of 'Inner'"` otherwise.

Is there any way to accomplish this? In my case `inner_` should have the same lifetime as `Outer`, and I'd rather not have to make it a pointer to an object that has to be manually allocated on the heap and freed in `dealloc`.

Comment: Thanks! For what it's worth, that one didn't show up in the list of suggested duplicates.

Comment: Yup. I found it by searching :)

Comment: Yeah, I searched for it at first, too, and found similar but slightly different questions. Didn't come across the one you linked. Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C++, instance variables must be [default constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultConstructible), and are default-constructed during allocation.

Unfortunately, there's not much [official documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#objcxx) to back this up, and what there is is [very old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105784/apples-using-c-with-objective-c-article-is-gone-can-anyone-give-me-a-new-a) and outdated.

Comment: [Further (and still outdated) reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.4/gcc/Objective_002dC-and-Objective_002dC_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html) on gcc's behavior.